# Could not convert string to float -Using Pandas and Numpy for a SVM Classifier

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, svm

I'm trying to use pandas to create a SVM classifier. I already generated my feature and save it using to_csv from pandas lib. This feature(Color) consists in a whole histogram. So, I have a list of 0 to 255 float values per line. There are 362 lines.
Here is a piece of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    train = pd.read_csv('Train.csv',index_col='Object')
    XTrain = train['Color']
    ColorLabel = train['ColorLabel']
    leTrain = LabelEncoder()
    leTrain.fit(ColorLabel)
    ColorLabel = leTrain.transform(ColorLabel)

    svm = SVC()
    parameters = {'kernel': ('linear', 'rbf'), 'C': (1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,0.05), 'gamma': (0.5,1, 2, 3, 'auto'),
                  'decision_function_shape': ('ovo', 'ovr'),'class_weight': [{0: 1,1: w2} for w2 in [2, 4, 6, 10,12]]}
    clf = GridSearchCV(svm, parameters,verbose = 2)
    clf.fit(XTrain, ColorLabel)
```

Im just trying to fit the feature column Color in SVC.fit, however I receive an error message that says:

> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 12.0, 2.0, 18.0, 36.0, 0.0, 87.0, 34.0, 13.0, 41.0, 30.0, 118.0, 137.0, 169.0, 530.0, 4684.0, 5746.0, 1975.0, 1815.0, 4079.0, 4725.0, 2411.0, 131.0, 434.0, 3799.0, 1435.0, 4380.0, 5.0, 0.0, 546.0, 0.0, 1695.0, 15.0, 0.0, 116.0, 82.0, 4.0, 52.0, 54.0, 4.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'

Here is the head of my Train.csv

> Object,Kurtosis,Skewness,Color,TextureLabel,ColorLabel
>   0122_LSG.jpg,-0.19026044432874611,-0.9694201939544961,"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 6.0, 16.0, 90.0, 47.0, 114.0, 126.0, 1918.0, 733.0, 5404.0, 3956.0, 12750.0, 13551.0, 3222.0, 3927.0, 5776.0, 4896.0, 3807.0, 9007.0, 8835.0, 1029.0, 684.0, 495.0, 172.0, 121.0, 125.0, 37.0, 93.0, 31.0, 96.0, 73.0, 7.0, 15.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]",L,S 0075_LSG.jpg,-0.25089779696431913,-0.5106815852572715,"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 16.0, 461.0, 6.0, 37.0, 216.0, 5.0, 348.0, 45.0, 264.0, 294.0, 316.0, 999.0, 3057.0, 3625.0, 5399.0, 2420.0, 6031.0, 6636.0, 7442.0, 801.0, 5958.0, 7289.0, 11785.0, 6150.0, 8537.0, 4414.0, 398.0, 489.0, 449.0, 155.0, 270.0, 64.0, 230.0, 51.0, 101.0, 121.0, 73.0, 76.0, 36.0, 46.0, 123.0, 45.0, 51.0, 1.0, 78.0, 28.0, 0.0, 4.0, 70.0, 53.0, 0.0, 41.0, 75.0, 4.0, 39.0, 1.0, 94.0, 0.0, 18.0, 198.0, 0.0, 4.0, 225.0, 16.0, 158.0, 147.0, 8.0, 0.0, 6.0, 22.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]",L,S 0157_LSP.jpg,-0.604961472275447,-0.8074495729146061,"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 48.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 0.0,

I TRIED ALL THE TYPES OF TYPE CASTING THAT I KNOW astype,dtype,converters... PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: SVM is looking for a single value in each row in the column. The issue you have is two-fold. First, your column appears to contain a very long list of floats stored as a string. You should be able to parse that into a list with `eval()` (though that method gets a lot of people very upset for some good reasons) but then you will have a list of values, which will also not ingest unless you parse it out into individual columns

Comment: @G.Anderson the `eval` issue can be avoided with `ast.literal_eval` here

Comment: @roganjosh fair point, but that still gets raked over the coals from what I've seen, though either should be reasonably safe in this use-case IMO

Comment: In this case, why not just use `map(float, a.split(', '))`?

Comment: @ G. Anderson  already tried eval and the ast solution it didn't work. These values are being converted to str by some pandas function because the histogram is the result  from cv.calcHist

Comment: In the source data frame, the `Color` column contained numpy arrays (apparently), not simple strings or numbers.  Since `csv` is inherently a simple 2d storage format - rows of comma separated data, complex cells of a dataframe have to be represented as a string.  That's what the `"[1,2,3,...]"` string represents, just `str(an_array)`.   The error means it's trying to convert this string into a float.

Comment: Why did you save the original dataframe with `to_csv`?  Did someone tell you that was the right format for a complex frame like yours?

Comment: @hpaulj no one I just followed the tutorials. How can I solve this? I spent all day trying to solve this.

Comment: Do you still have the original data frame around?

Comment: My feature needs to be all the 255 values. It together means the histogram of h channel of my image

Comment: Yes, I have all data.

Comment: Use `to_pickle` to save the data frame in a way that can be reloaded easily.  Your dataframe is too complicated to save as `csv`.

Answer (score 0):

XTrain =[list(map(float, hist)) for hist in train['Color']]

Plus using ; as sep when reading and writing file
SOLVE IT .